# How to change ReportPortal containers timezone?

Tags: docker-compose, timezone, reportportal

Following the [installation guide](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal/blob/master/README.md#reportportalio), ReportPortal is successfully deployed. Everything works fine, except for one thing... Containers time zone is always UTC. My CI servers are located in UTC+3, so, for example, launch reported at 00.30 is shown on widget as yesterday's one.

Most of images are alpine based, without installed tzdata. I tried to add hosts `etc/localtime` as a volume (`/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro`) but it doesn't help.

I've got the same result on RHEL 7 and Win 10 local machine with Docker Toolbox.
Appreciate if somebody share his experience with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it.

Actually, that's enough to change a timezone in api container only.
Adding environment variable TZ is solving the issue. So I just added it to the docker-compose file:

```
api:
    image: reportportal/service-api:4.3.0
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - RP_PROFILES=docker
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp
      - TZ=Asia/Jerusalem
    restart: always
```